# set a property for each node in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I want to set a property called degree for each node existing in my db that should count all the relationship for each node.

I wrote this, but it doesn't work.

```
MATCH p=(n:Directed_Node)--()
WITH count(p) AS counter
SET n.Degree=counter
return *
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this to set it on each node.

```
MATCH (n:Directed_Node)
SET n.Degree=size((n)--())
```

If you just want to get all the relationships for each node though this would likely be a better approach. As the number of relationships will likely be a dynamic value it would be expensive to always calculate it and store it every time. The database has this information readily available so this query will be very perfomant (with the caveat of course that you are going after every `Directed_Node`; if there are millions then it will never be *fast*) and always accurate.

```
MATCH (n:Directed_Node)
RETURN size((n)--())
```

Comment: For what I need to do, the fist code is perfect for my case. Thank u very much